# iMacros use Input Username and Password in same Datasource

Tags: forms, email, input, passwords, imacros

I have set up a datasource on my iMacros to fill in e-mail from a list but I also want it to fill in password from same list

my list looks like `email:password`
it only inputs the email how can i make it input email and on password `input :password`?

please help

```
VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\Me\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\emails.txt
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAB T=1
CLEAR
URL GOTO=https://example.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL FORM=ID:ap_signin_form ATTR=ID:ap_email CONTENT={{!COL1}}
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:ap_signin_form ATTR=ID:ap_password CONTENT=heaven777
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:ap_signin_form ATTR=ID:signInSubmit-input
URL GOTO=https://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\Me\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\emails.txt
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAB T=1
CLEAR
URL GOTO=https://example.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL FORM=ID:ap_signin_form ATTR=ID:ap_email CONTENT={{!COL1}}
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:ap_signin_form ATTR=ID:ap_password CONTENT=heaven777
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:ap_signin_form ATTR=ID:signInSubmit-input
URL GOTO=https://www.example.com/
```

I just want to specific the code.